# Return all rows from 2 tables and information from a 3rd

Tags: sql

I am having troubles getting the desired results.

I have 3 tables: tbl_Policy 'a', tbl_User 'b', tbl_Reviewed 'c'.

When a user reviews a policy, the userid from 'b' and the policyid from 'a' are entered into 'c' with the current date (datereviewed).

EDIT: I need to see all the users, all of the policies, and if they've been reviewed.

For this example: John has reviewed all 3 policies;
James has reviewed the IT policy only; and
Sarah hasn't reviewed any

Ideally the output would be:

```
User     Policy      Date Reviewed
John     HR          January 2, 2014
John     IT          January 3, 2014
John     Smoking     January 4, 2014
James    HR          NULL
James    IT          January 5, 2014
James    Smoking     NULL
Sarah    HR          NULL
Sarah    IT          NULL
Sarah    Smoking     NULL
```

With the following query I can get all users and all policies, but I get an entry for all 3 policies for each policy that has been completed..

```
  select username, policyname, datereviewed
  from tbl_policy a, tbl_user b LEFT JOIN tbl_reviewed c ON c.userid = b.userid
```

Using the example above, this outputs:

```
User     Policy      Date Reviewed
John     HR          January 2, 2014
John     IT          January 2, 2014
John     Smoking     January 2, 2014
John     HR          January 3, 2014
John     IT          January 3, 2014
John     Smoking     January 3, 2014
John     HR          January 4, 2014
John     IT          January 4, 2014
John     Smoking     January 4, 2014
James    HR          January 2, 2014
James    IT          January 2, 2014
James    Smoking     January 2, 2014
Sarah    HR          NULL
Sarah    IT          NULL
Sarah    Smoking     NULL
```

I hope this is clear enough to give you an idea and hopefully help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A data dictionary of the three tables might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix different types of joins in the `from` clause.  In fact, just *never* use a comma there:

```
select u.username, p.policyname, r.datereviewed
from tbl_user u LEFT JOIN
     tbl_reviewed r
     ON u.userid = r.userid LEFT JOIN
     tbl_policy p
     ON p.policyid = r.policyid;
```

This starts with `tbl_user` because you want to see all users, presumably whether or not they have any reviewed policies.

I'm guessing at the join condition for the policies.

EDIT:

Now I see what you want to do.  You want a row for every user and every policy along with the date:

```
select u.username, p.policyname, r.datereviewed
from tbl_user u cross join
     tbl_policy p LEFT JOIN
     tbl_reviewed r
     ON u.userid = r.userid and
        p.policyid = r.policyid
order by username, policyname;
```

Comment: I don't normally use Cartesian joins, but it's the only thing that's gotten me close.  Your suggestion gives me all users and whether they have reviewed the policy, but it doesn't show for all the policies.

Comment: @JGow . . . I didn't fully understand what you wanted.  See the edited query.